# WinApi32 C Scroll Bar Control (Slider)

Tags: c, winapi, scroll

I would like to ask how I can create a scroll bar (slider) in WinApi32 C so I can
send serial port data depending on the position of the thumb in the scroll bar.

Comment: See the Scroll Bar Control technical article at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997557.aspx

Comment: Can you be more specific what your problem is? Is your problem with a scroll bar or a slider? (They are different controls.) Is your problem with creating the control? Is the problem with reading the thumb position? Is the problem with sending serial port data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a window with a scroll bar by adding the `WS_HSCROLL` and/or `WS_VSCROLL` styles to your `CreateWindow()` call.

```
hWnd = CreateWindow("YourWnd","Name", 
  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 250,
  NULL,NULL,            
  hInstance,NULL
);
```

You can then check the location by calling the [`GetScrollPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`GetScrollInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

See MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997557.aspx) for more info.